# Tensorflow example not finding contrib.tensorboard.plugins

Tags: tensorflow

With TensorFlow 2.0, I want to run [word2vec](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec) tutorial, but get this error:

```
$ python word2vec_basic.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word2vec_basic.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
ImportError: No module named contrib.tensorboard.plugins
```

I have build TF successfully where you can verify that tensorboard has been installed.

```
$ pip install -U --user /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl 
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
  Processing /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: gast==0.2.2 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.2.2)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.22.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.16.4)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.0.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wrapt>=1.11.1 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.11.2)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.6.1 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.9.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.1.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: backports.weakref>=1.0rc1; python_version < "3.4" in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.0.post1)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.0.8)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.33.4)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: functools32>=3.2.3 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.2.3.post2)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.12.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py>=0.7.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.7.1)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.3.2)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.1.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.1.7)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: enum34>=1.1.6; python_version < "3.4" in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.1.6)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorflow-estimator<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.0.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: astor>=0.6.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.8.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: mock>=2.0.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.0.5)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: futures>=2.2.0; python_version < "3.2" in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from grpcio>=1.8.6->tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.3.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools>=41.0.0 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (41.0.1)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (0.15.5)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: markdown>=2.6.8 in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (3.1.1)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: h5py in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow==2.0.0) (2.9.0)
  Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" in /home/mahmood/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow==2.0.0) (1.0.2)
  Installing collected packages: tensorflow
    Found existing installation: tensorflow 2.0.0
      Uninstalling tensorflow-2.0.0:
        Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-2.0.0
  Successfully installed tensorflow-2.0.0
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Then you can verify